# Запуск приложения с помощью java

Tags: java

Как с помощью `java` запустить графическое приложение из Linux, тоесть получить доступ к консоли.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используйте [`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("gedit");
Process process = builder.start();
```

Если у программы есть параметры, их нужно прописать через запятую

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("gedit","a.txt");
Process process = builder.start();
```

Comment: @ДенисКотляров, экранируйте кавычки.

Comment: Кавычки экранированы, еслиб они небыли экранированы яб получал ошибки.

Comment: Даже без ковычек не запускается, а если в консоль ввести то все отлично

Comment: @ДенисКотляров, а обычный gedit открывается?

Comment: Вот удивительно но обычный gedit Открылся

Comment: @ДенисКотляров, вам там обязательно в кавычках параметр отправлять?

Comment: Питон, пхп тоже отлично запустили `notify-send "TEST"` а вот джава что-то творит

Comment: Я даже без кавычек, просто пробелы заменяю на _ не запускается, копирую этотже запрос из java в консоль и все работает

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32902/discussion-between-leqada-and--).