# Запуск приложения с правами администратора, Java

Tags: java

Есть ли возможность в Java запускать приложение с правами администратора? Программно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, есть такая возможность. Для этого надо выполнить 2 шага:

1. Выяснить, как из консоли на целевой платформе запустить приложение от имени Администратора;
2. При помощи `ProcessBuilder`-а выполнить эту команду из своего приложения (cм. тут: [Запуск приложения с помощью java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/474091/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-java) ).

Comment: Консольные команды - это не серьёзно. Вызвать функцию операционной системы для запуска программы, используя JNI или JNA.

Comment: @Sergey Это по-моему будет слишком костыльно. Хотя, можете попробовать дать свой ответ с подробным описанием действий и быть может он больше понравится топикстартеру.

Comment: @Sergey, в Java так не делают. Есть специальный класс ProcessBuilder, им и нужно пользоваться. Запуск "консольного" приложения с этой точки зрения ничем не отличается от запуска "не консольного".

Comment: @Nofate Всё-таки есть небольшая разница в том запустите ли вы приложение сразу, либо сначала приложение, которое запустит другое приложение, которое запустит третье, и т.д. пока не запуститься то, ради которого эта цепочка запусков и задумывалась. Нет?