# Как получить права администратора в Java для выполнения дальнейших задач

Tags: java

С помощью FileReader я запускаю системный файл и пытаюсь изменить строки в нем. Но я не могу это сделать, если мое приложение не запущено от имени администратора.

```
private BufferedReader fileReader(String path) {
   FileReader fileReader = null;
   try {
       fileReader = new FileReader(path);
   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
   return bufferedReader;
}

private String fileWriter(String path) {
   try {
       BufferedReader bR = fileReader(filePath);
       while ((line = bR.readLine()) != null) {
          ...
          ...
       }
   } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   return result;
}
```

Скажите, как запросить повышение прав в коде, чтобы при использовании моей программы не от имени администратора мне не нужно было перезапускать ее с повышенными правами для корректной работы?

OS - Windows. Но хотелось бы получить общее решение, если оно есть, потому что приложение используется на разных платформах

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, только через "*Запустить от имени Администратора*" или `sudo java -jar <program-binary.jar>` в *NIX.

UPD: Извиняюсь, не полностью прочитал вопрос. Можно использовать [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) для запуска команды от админа, вот пример такого способа:

```
// Первый аргумент конструктора - имя программы, второй - аргументы.
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar <jarname>.jar");
Process process = builder.start();
```

[Источник](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/474091/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-java)