# Запуск exe файла и передача значений Java

Tags: java

Всем привет, вообщем столкнулся с такой проблемой.

Есть такая программа XnView - для уникализации изображений, и от них же есть приложение которое работает через терминал т.е. можно проделать все тоже самое что и в программе с интерфейсом только через командную строку.

Вопрос: каким образом я могу взаимодействовать с командной строкой только через IDEA, куда копать?

Через терминал измение изображение примерно выглядит так:

```
/Users/nikita/Desktop/NConvert-2/nconvert -out jpeg -resize 640 480 go.jpeg
```

Хотелось бы все это автоматизировать и превратить в небольшую программку

Comment: Копать в сторону [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).

Comment: Посмотрите этот вопрос, направление такое же: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/474091/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-java/474092